# Accessing outer scope from inner scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a type that looks a little something like this:

```
var x = function(){
    this.y = function(){

    }

    this.z = function(){
        ...
        this.A = function(){
            CALLING POINT
        }
    }
}
```

From calling point, I'm attempting to call function this.y. I don't need to pass any parameters, but when I set some stuff from this.A, I need to call this.y.

Is this possible? I'm OK with passing extra parameters to functions to make it possible.

Comment: It depends on how you call your methods, specifically `A`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you clarify how this isn't a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) They look the same to me: accessing a property on `this` from an outer function scope.

Comment: @apsillers: I thought the code there was sufficiently different it would be unclear to the OP how those answers addressed this setup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, you can assign `this` reference to another variable and then call function `y` on it

```js
this.z = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.A = function() {
        self.y();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Version with `bind`, basically this adds a new method `a` to the object.

```js
var X = function () {
    this.y = function () {
        document.write('y<br>');
    }

    this.z = function () {
        document.write('z<br>');
        this.a = function () {
            document.write('a<br>');
            this.y();
        }
    }.bind(this);
};

var x = new X;
//x.a(); // does not exist
x.z();   // z
x.a();   // a y
```

Working example with saved inner `this`.

```js
var X = function () {
    var that = this; // <--

    this.y = function () {
        document.write('y<br>');
    }

    this.Z = function () {
        document.write('Z<br>');
        this.a = function () {
            document.write('a<br>');
            that.y();
        }
    }
}

var x = new X,
    z = new x.Z; // Z

z.a(); // a y
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `function()` you can try modern JavaScript or Typescript `()=>`. I also like `.bind(this)`.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot because `this.y()` is not within the scope that `this.A()` is in. You can if you set `this.y()` to a global function `y`:

```
var y = function() {};
var x = function() {
    this.y = y;
    this.z = function() {
       ...
       this.A = function() {
           this.y(); // will be successful in executing because this.y is set to the y function.
       };
    }
};
```