# Calling outer function from inner function of another outer function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say that:

```
 a() {
  console.log("i am a")
}

 b() {
   c() {
    //call function a here 
  }
}
```

How do I call function `a` from function `c`?

Comment: Can you please make sure indentation is correct in your sample code? Also, why don't you just go `a()` inside `c` to call `a`?

Comment: The same way you call any other function.

Comment: i forgot to add that i am using typescript

Comment: Invalid syntax. You're using methods of a class/object?

Comment: The same way you call any other function on an instance.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, though your question is really unclear because you haven't described the issue you're having. You can't access `this` from inside the `c` function, correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing outer scope from inner scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878587/accessing-outer-scope-from-inner-scope)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20279484)

Answer (score -1):

functions declared like you are declaring them are hoisted to the top of the scope. `a` is available globally and can be called by anything inside the same global scope.

Comment: The code is apparently inside some kind of `class` and isn't global.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem with using an arrow function on parameter of c.

Answer (score -1):

The way your functions are defined shows that c is nested inside of b which effects the scope when the function executes. First, you would have to figure out a way to call function c. Since it is inside of function b, you will first need to call function b to get to function c. Accessing function c is not possible with your code.

The below code would allow you to call function c, which then calls function a.

```js
function a() {
  console.log("i am a")
}

function b() {
   this.c = function() {
    //call function a here
    window.a();
  }
  
  return this;
}

b().c()
```